# Clicking on inbox notifications in mobile Firefox on iOS takes me to footer of linked page

Tags: bug, global-inbox, firefox, mobile

Since I think a couple of weeks back, clicking on inbox notifications in Firefox on iOS to open them in a new tab now opens the desired page, but scrolls it down to the bottom of the page rather than to the content I was notified about in the inbox.

Unlike with similar errors in the past, reloading the page to hopefully scroll it to the correct place on the page no longer works; however, manually editing the URL in the location bar, but not making any changes to it finally reaches the linked content.

I'm unsure whether this is a bug in Firefox for iOS or a problem with the site. This used to work much better.

As an example, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136413398?noredirect=1 is a link I received in by inbox recently. This particular link works fine on my phone, too; but this is one I copy/pasted from the desktop version of my inbox (where I am using Chrome on macOS).

When I actually click on the link, the URL changes to [Move subdirectories to parent based on name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77373497/move-subdirectories-to-parent-based-on-name/77373586?noredirect=1#comment136413398_77373586) (both on the desktop and on mobile), but this one is what seems to take me to the page footer in Firefox on my phone.

I have reported [similar behavior when opening "modified by" links on the start page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392228/modified-link-sometimes-takes-me-to-footer) of the site; this could be a manifestation of the same problem, or a different one.